# Unknown classes - subset of features

Tags: classification, weka, feature-extraction

If you have a problem for which you nothing about other than the object and features involved, but do not know how these group together, i.e. you want to see if there are natural groups based on the data. Is there any value in taking the 10 features of this new object (say guitars from the 1980s) and splitting them into two functional sets of 5 features - one group relating to human things (like colour, price etc) and the other being physical characteristics (weight, wood type) etc ?
An example of a group I wish to find is say the difference between electric and acoustic, but we dont know. It could end up that the data tells us that there is a difference between American and European guitars, due to price, weight etc.

So the idea is to training my model against the first set of 5 features, then against the second and use these two results in some fashion to shape a prediction?

Is there a particular name for this procedure or is there any merit in it?

I am trying to get to grips with breaking toy problems and gaining the most information out of unknown data.

I am a genetic researcher and want to learn some classifications etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper methods - these determine subsets of features for use in training and accessing performance. However they add or remove features based on performance.

However, is there any merit to feature extraction by simply splitting the feature vector, and training on each of these? And then combining or analyzing the results of these two independent feature vectors.